# Status code = 0 when using xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } in jQuery $ajax call with Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, cookies, cors

I'm using

```
xhrFields : { 
  withCredentials: true 
}
```

in jQuery $ajax calls, in order to send session cookies within my queries.

The call gives a correct status code on my apache logs (401/200 depending if the cookie is set), but Firefox always receives a status=0 (i.e. an error in $.ajax())
If I remove this xhrFields section, status code is OK (but cookies are not sent)

Here's the response object I receive in Firefox with the xhrFields setup:

```
{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

My Apache config is CORS-enabled, and also allows Access-Control-Allow-Credentials (here are the corresponding HTTP headers)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Is there something missing, either in the AJAX call, or on the webserver config?

NB: This works perfectly fine in Chrome

Comment: Did you check other browsers (like G Chrome)?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Chrome, and am also using the full origin and not a wildcard origin.

Answer (score 11):

You probably have to specify the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header more explicitly than *.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Requests_with_credentials says:

> **Important note:** when responding to a credentialed request,  server
>   must specify a domain, and cannot use wild carding.

Answer (score 0):

In web applications, with CORS setting if you use **withCredientials=true**, then need to make sure few things as you are requesting server to expose response header like status, cookies etc. in script.

1. You return only one valid origin i.e. domain value to header called "access-control-allow-origin" in response as follows:

access-control-allow-origin: {domain with protocol and port if any}

e.g.
access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:9191

or

access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com

2. Make sure you set another header called "access-control-allow-credentials" to true in response as follows:

access-control-allow-credentials: true

This should make it work for you to access response headers like status and authentication headers etc.